# Render a value from scope in a directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am facing the next problem. I am trying to create a directive with some template like the example down:

```
 $templateCache.put("menuColumns.html",
       "<div id=\"grid-table\">"+
       "<table id=\"table-{{gridOptions.gridName}}\" class=\"table table-striped table-hover\" >" +
       "     <thead>"+
       "        <tr class=\"header cursor-hand\">"+
       "            <th ng-show=\"gridOptions.canDragDropRows\" style=\"width: 15px;\"></th>" +
       "            <th ng-repeat=\"itemColumn in gridOptions.gridColumnDefs \" " +
       "                ng-class=\"selectColumnStyle('{{itemColumn.field}}')\" >{{itemColumn.displayName}}</th>" +
       "            <th style=\"width: 50px;\"></th>"+
       "        </tr>"+
       "    </thead>"+
       "</table></div>"
   );
```

In my controller I have a variable like this:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
    canDragDropRows: true,
    gridName: 'items-list',
    gridColumnDefs: [{ field: "Id", width: "25%", displayName: "Id"},
                     { field: "Description", width: "25%", displayName: "Name" },
                     { field: "Location", width: "25%", displayName: "Installation" },
                     { field: "Equipment", width: "25%", displayName: "Equipment"}]
 };
```

As you can see in the ng-class inside the template, I'm trying to call a function called selectColumnStyle and I need to pass as a parameter the value of the {{itemColumn.field}}.

When the directive tries to render, I am not getting those  that have the ng-class. It seems that is not the best way to pass parameters to some functions.

Do you know a way to do it? The this is that I need the name of the field inside the function.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us code of directive, or jsFiddle or Plunk example. Function selectColumnStyle() should be declared in your directive.

Comment: Hi @OZ_. I've realized that something else was altering my directive. Right now it is working after some changes in the code (but not in the code section I was asking for). This is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abottoni/JSysr/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research in my code, (I've tried what Mathew Berg told me); I've realized that something else was altering my directive. Right now it is working after some changes in the code (but not in the code section I was asking for).

```
 $templateCache.put("menuColumns.html",
   "<div id=\"grid-table\">"+
   "<table id=\"table-{{gridOptions.gridName}}\" class=\"table table-striped table-hover\" >" +
   "     <thead>"+
   "        <tr class=\"header cursor-hand\">"+
   "            <th ng-show=\"gridOptions.canDragDropRows\" style=\"width: 15px;\"></th>" +
   "            <th ng-repeat=\"itemColumn in gridOptions.gridColumnDefs \" " +
   "                ng-class=\"selectColumnStyle('{{itemColumn.field}}')\" >{{itemColumn.displayName}}</th>" +
   "            <th style=\"width: 50px;\"></th>"+
   "        </tr>"+
   "    </thead>"+
   "</table></div>"
```

);

The code with the {{ }} is working fine. This is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abottoni/JSysr/7/) if someone need this !

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the {{ }}:

ng-class=\"selectColumnStyle(itemColumn.field)\" >{{itemColumn.displayName}}

Comment: Hi @Mathew. I've realized that something else was altering my directive. Right now it is working after some changes in the code (but not in the code section I was asking for). The code with the {{ }} is working fine. This is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abottoni/JSysr/7/)